# checkbox list calling server with possible delay

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, checkbox, knockout.js

I am working with jquery & knockout for my client side development. My application is built in asp.net mvc4.

I have a control on my page that produces a an array of checkboxes. The behaviour I have is when a checkbox is checked or unchecked a server side call is made to render some data. This call does some processing on the server side that is heavy.

I am concerned users will come along and "check" "check" "check" the checkbox list quickly making multiple server side call.

I am looking for suggestion to prevent multiple calls to the server happening in this situation? I considered a delay after the user checks the checkbox to give them time to wait to check others. Is there any more elegant way to do this though?

Comment: On change, disable checkboxes, wait for server callback, enable on success? First thought.

Comment: Thought of that but it doesn't give the user the best experience. I also thought of having a loading icon over them.

Comment: How long does it take from the "check" to the server response?

Comment: You should have a look in the [throttle extender](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/throttle-extender.html) if you are using Knockout for the chekbox